# Unable to preload clause.Associations

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-fiber

I am using GORM in combination with Fiber. When querying all users with preloaded `clause.Associations` I get the following error:

```
can't preload field @@@as@@@ for entities.User
```

What does that mean? Without the `preload` of `clause.Associations` it works normally and but it does not show one-to-one associations.

```
func UsersGetAll(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db := database.DBConn
    users := []entities.User{}
    records := db.Preload(clause.Associations).Find(&users)
    if records.Error != nil {
        log.Println(records.Error)
        return c.Status(500).SendString(records.Error.Error())
    }

    return c.JSON(records.Value)
}
```

Comment: What is  clause.Associations ? Can you show  your model used in post ?

Comment: `clause.Associations` is from the GORM documentation (https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload-All) and is basically the expression `@@@as@@@`  used for eager preload all associations (without one-to-many and many-to-many). The User model consists of regular fields like `Name` and `Age`, but also one-to-one associations like `Address` of type `Address`, which I want to eagerly preload and does not work. Including the one-to-one associations explicitly in `preload` works though.

Answer (score 0):

Well looks like a problem with gorm tags:
I will suppose the struct is something like this :

```
type Address struct {
ID int `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey"`
}
type User struct {
Name string `gorm:"column:name"`
Age string `gorm:"column:age"`
Address Address `gorm:"references:ID"`
}
```

And the code:

```
user:=User{}
if err:=db.Preload("Address").Find(&user).Error {
panic(err)
}
```

I think you also should look at this: [Gorm relationship error: need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588796/gorm-relationship-error-need-to-define-a-valid-foreign-key-for-relations-or-it)